# ANR due to deadlock between app and widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an android app that a) performs an updateData() function (querying content providers and HTTP requests from internet among other things) in a thread, and b) has a home screen widget that performs the same updateData() function every 30mins (not in a thread).

a) looks like this:

```
public class MoodMain extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(...)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                     updateData(this);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

b) looks like this :

```
public class MoodAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider { 
    public void onUpdate(Context context, ...)
    { 
        updateData(context);
    } }
```

Now people are reporting ANRs where threads are stopped at same place in updateData(context), one thread for a) and one for b).  Stack traces look like the following:

1st example:

> "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N
>   obj=0x40025ad8 self=0xcd80   | sysTid=23053 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=default handle=-1345017808   | schedstat=( 5672943129 29267974835
>   13299 )   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:370)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
>   ...
>
> "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   s=N obj=0x4629ba88 self=0x2d1750   | sysTid=23062 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=default handle=2955408   | schedstat=( 53100602 8822875969 600 ) 
>   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:370)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245) ...

2nd example:

> "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N
>   obj=0x40020a30 self=0xcd88   | sysTid=19319 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=default handle=-1345026000   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getaddrinfo(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:508)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:280)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:310)   at
>   java.net.InetSocketAddress.(InetSocketAddress.java:110) ...
>
> "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   s=N obj=0x458842e8 self=0x245cc0   | sysTid=20153 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=default handle=2388904   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getaddrinfo(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:508) ...
>
> "Thread-8" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N
>   obj=0x45867030 self=0x22c528   | sysTid=20151 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=default handle=2277944   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getaddrinfo(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:508) ...   at
>   com.admob.android.ads.i.d(AdMobURLConnector.java:153)   at
>   com.admob.android.ads.b.a(AdRequester.java:206)   at
>   com.admob.android.ads.AdView$b.run(AdView.java:655)

Looks like some kind of task deadlock.  Any ideas how to solve this anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is the fact I am doing a long process in the onUpdate() function of the widgetProvider.  I modified my code to spawn a thread to perform the intensive functionality, and so far, no more freezes have been reported from users.