# ANR when calling system service (e.g. telephony service)

Tags: android, native, android-anr-dialog

since Android 8 I have an increased number of ANRs reported in the Google Play Developer console. All of them have in common that the ANR seems to be not directly related to my code but always related to native system calls. 
See the following examples:

Example 1:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73798b10 self=0x73186a3a00
  | sysTid=12505 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x731d5c49b0
  | state=S schedstat=( 28971945984 27609449667 173830 ) utm=1926 stm=970 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd4e3d000-0x7fd4e3f000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001db2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000e1f30  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
  #02  pc 00000000004e21a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+440)
  #03  pc 00000000004e1fa4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
  #04  pc 0000000000991b3c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+220)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:761)
  at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.getService (ServiceManagerNative.java:123)
  at android.os.ServiceManager.getService (ServiceManager.java:66)
  at android.telephony.SubscriptionManager.getPhoneId (SubscriptionManager.java:953)
  at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName (TelephonyManager.java:1693)
  at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName (TelephonyManager.java:1679)

    [...]

  at com.xx.x.v$1.onSignalStrengthsChanged (MyPhoneStateObserver.java:99)
  at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage (PhoneStateListener.java:349)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Example 2:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x737b5bb0 self=0x7e0f4a3a00
  | sysTid=24248 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7e144ca9b0
  | state=S schedstat=( 36923767919 38940772860 261304 ) utm=2358 stm=1334 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fdc8c2000-0x7fdc8c4000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001da2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000e1ee4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
  #02  pc 00000000004e35c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+440)
  #03  pc 00000000004e33c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
  #04  pc 000000000098b14c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+220)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:751)
  at android.net.INetworkStatsService$Stub$Proxy.getMobileIfaces (INetworkStatsService.java:318)

     [...]

  at com.xx.(MyPhoneStateObserver.java)
  at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage (PhoneStateListener.java:331)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

**Open questions**

What I can see from these traces is that every time the system seems to be stuck during a service call e.g. to the telephony service. Is there any explanation why this happens? 
I expect an ANR to occur if the execution time is >~10sec so there must be a deadlock? 
A possible solution would be to move all the event handling to another thread but this does not explain the issue and I expect that the async execution would also be stuck?

**Edit:** The funny thing is that all of these ANRs are titled with:

> Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
>   flg=0x50200010 }

Comment: Are you listening to this intent with any filter anywhere? I had the very same ANRs, but I was listening through manifest. Register your receiver in the activity, not in the manifest. Many things have changed with 8.0 and later.

Comment: I am only using dynamic receivers which work fine i guess - the question to me is why do phone state events show up as display changed events in the console..

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with background execution limits in Android 8. When your app is idle, there are limits on ints background services and also some broadcast limitations https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background . You could review your code according to optimization guide https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization

Comment: @and_dev is possible for you to post what you're doing inside `MyPhoneStateObserver` ?

Comment: @MadScientist Unfortunately this is not possible, only some minor updates. It should not exceed seconds of time

Comment: @and_dev there's an anr for stacktrace as well? are you doing any recursive calls there?

Comment: @MadScientist That's the whole stacktrace I got from the Google Play Console, no recursive calls or any other extended operation. One some other traces I noticed the "The "main" (tid=1) thread is in suspended state. This is likely due to garbage collection." -> but that's not the case with the ones I posted initially

Comment: please post your gradle file.@and_dev

Comment: Does you app have home screen widgets? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017783/anr-due-to-deadlock-between-app-and-widget

Comment: @and_dev Where you able to figure out the cause for ANR? If yes, please update your post. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try following I found a similar error stack for billing:

Do not call any network calls, reading or writing files, operating databases etc in your ***MyPhoneStateObserver*** or any broadcast receiver. You might be calling some method which is blocking the application thread. I would advice call these kinds of methods from a **separate thread**.

**Is there any explanation why this happens?** 
I think you should double check your ***MyPhoneStateObserver*** class, I guess you are making *some network calls, reading or writing files, operating databases* or any operation which should be done in the separate thread. The operations/code you have implemented in this class or overridden method try to do it in a separate thread.

**I expect an ANR to occur if the execution time is >~10sec so there must be a deadlock?** ANR occurs when the main thread is blocked for a few time. Specifically, 5 seconds in an Activity, 10 seconds in a BroadcastReceiver and 20 seconds in a Service.

**A possible solution would be to move all the event handling to another thread but this does not explain the issue and I expect that the async execution would also be stuck?** Yes, you are right you have to move your code to another thread. But I don't think so asysnctask will work here, in services or background listeners I believe you would need to use thread.

Comment: is the above information provided to you is helpful? if not please let me know I would try to figure out the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your error code.

> Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50200010 }

Please try using Wakelock. This will prevent system from shutting off your apps process until you relese the wakelock.

You can aquire wakelock as follows

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
    "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Please refer documentation for more details. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#java

Also refer to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background 
As pointed out in comments, android system tries to optimize resources and that may be the issue that's causing ANRs in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wakelock is not a solution here and would also not prevent the system ANR I guess

Comment: Did you try using wakelock?